# In magento 2 Not show the value after ajax response in UI Component

Tags: knockout.js, magento2, magento2.4

i am trying to get shipping amount in seller wise in checkout summary i got the amount from ajax i render the data in html but it is not showing after ajax without ajax it is working
**Magento_Checkout\js\view\summary\item\details.js**

```js
define([
  'uiComponent',
  'jquery',
  'mage/url'
], function(Component, $, urlBuilder) {
  'use strict';

  return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
      template: 'Magento_Checkout/summary/item/details'
    },

    getShippingAmount: function(quoteItem) {
      var ajaxUrl = urlBuilder.build('checkout/shipping');

      $.ajax({
        url: ajaxUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          itemId: quoteItem.item_id
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          return data.amount;
        }
      });
    },

    // ...
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- 
Magento_Checkout\template\summary\item\details.html
-->
<span data-bind="text: getShippingAmount($parent)"></span>
```

In html file path ***Magento_Checkout\template\summary\item\details.html***

i need to show amount from after ajax call

Answer (score 1):

I have not used magneto before, but I would be doing something like this.

```js
define([
  'uiComponent',
  'jquery',
  'mage/url'
], function(Component, $, urlBuilder) {
  'use strict';
  var shippingAmount = ko.observable();

  function getShippingAmount(quoteItem) {
    var ajaxUrl = urlBuilder.build('checkout/shipping');
    var result;
    $.ajax({
      url: ajaxUrl,
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        itemId: quoteItem.item_id
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        shippingAmount(data.amount);
      }
    });
  }


  return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
      template: 'Magento_Checkout/summary/item/details'
    },

    getShippingAmount: getShippingAmount,
    shippingAmount: shippingAmount
    

    // ...
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- 
Magento_Checkout\template\summary\item\details.html
-->
<span data-bind="text: shippingAmount"></span>
<button data-bind="click: getShippingAmount($parent)">Get Shipping Amount<button>
```